# Fetch data from server in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where I want to implement different types of messages depending by the data from server.

```
const submit = () => {
  setSubmit(true);
  dispatch(data)
}
```

This is my state, which checks if user clicked on submit or not:

```
const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);
```

From server I get messages related to fetching data:

```
 const isCreated = selector.createReducer.createSuccess;
 const isError = selector.createReducer.error.message;
```

And my `useEffect` which should call the messages depending by user:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if (submit) {
       if (isCreated) {
         seSubmit(false)
         message.success({ content: 'success'});
       }
        if (isError) {
          isSubmit(false)
          message.error({ content: isError});
        }
    }
  },[isCreated, submit, isError])
```

The issue is next:
I want to trigger these messages from `useEffect` when the `submit` is true and depending by the messages from server to call one message or another, but now when I get the messages in useEffect, I get something like this:

```
submit===true  isError="message error"  isCreated=false
second render in useEffect
submit===false  isError="message error"  isCreated=false
third render in useEffect
submit===false  isError=undefined  isCreated=null
forth render in useEffect
submit===false  isError=undefined  isCreated=true
```

So I get the needed data with delay, you can see:
`forth render in useEffect submit===false  isError=undefined  isCreated=true`

 And till i get the forthrender, the first render `submit===true  isError="message error"  isCreated=false` will be triggered and I will get error message event it is success in the forth render.
Question: How to create the rght condition for messages? What new conditions should I create to get the right result?

Comment: the `useEffect` should run only when `submit` equals to `true` right? If yes, then try use only `submit` in `useEffect`

Comment: @lala, now i also use submit in useEffect

Comment: this seems like something that should be handled by your server's logic as opposed to the client.

Comment: i reckoned when `submit` function triggered. That when you update your `state` with `dispatch(data)`. And those data got updated (with delay) into both your `isCreated` & `isError` state. Am I right?

Comment: @lala, yes, right. What is the solution in this case?

Comment: try `dispatch(data)` before setting `setSubmit(true)`

Answer (score 0):

try handle your `fetch` call inside your `useEffect`, like so:-

1. no initialize of `isCreated` and `isError` in your `context` or `reducer`

```
const [isCreated, setIsCreated] = useState(false)
const [isError, setIsError] = useState('')

// handle submission to server
useEffect(() => {
  (async() => {
   // should be async since fetching response from server
    if(submit) {
      // do fetch data or call action/function that handle fetching of data
      await dispatch(data)
    }
  })()  
}, [submit])

// handle isCreated
const isItCreated = (isCreated) => {
  if(isCreated) {
    message.success({ content: 'success'});
    return true
  } else return false
}

// handle isError
const isItError = (isError) => {
  if(isError) {
    message.error({ content: isError})
    return true
  } else return false
}

return (
  <>
  {isItCreated(isCreated) && 'doSomething'}
  {isItError(isError) && 'doSomething'}
  </>
)
```

2. if you have `isCreated` & `isError` `initialize` `state` handle by your `context` or `reducer`, then do this:-

```
// handle submission to server
useEffect(() => {
  (async() => {
   // should be async since fetching response from server
    if(submit) {
      // do fetch data or call action/function that handle fetching of data
      let {isCreated, isError} = await dispatch(data)

      if (isCreated) {
        message.success({ content: 'success'});
      }
      if (isError)
        message.error({ content: isError});
      }
      
      setIsSubmit(false)
    }
  })()  
}, [submit])
```